# Change default value depend on Sales quotation or order odoo

Tags: odoo

I want to change default value for some field in quotation and order.I mean if I create quotation,the default value is one and if i create order, the default value is another value.How can I do that? I think quotation and sale order share sale.order model.Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by overriding this function: default_get() or you can set a default value for the field in the declaration default= your_value
I hope this may help you.

Comment: I want to know is different default value for each quotation creation and sale order creation.I think your answer will get same default value for them.

Comment: excuse me I did not really understand.can you explain more

Answer (score 0):

You can use the action context values used to filter quotations from orders (or you can overide window actions and define yours).

For example, the current record is a quotation if the context attribute `search_default_my_quotation` is set.

***Example:***

```
def _get_default_value(self):
    if 'search_default_my_quotation' in self.env.context:
        return 'Quotation'
    else:
        return "Order"

note = fields.Text(default=_get_default_value)
```

Comment: Did you succeed to set the default value depending on the context?

Answer (score 0):

Quotations and sale order are differ by it's stage , no doubt both model (table) is same.

but for user friendly architecture they need to separate them with it's stages.

means if you have quotation that is in draft stage odoo say it's quotation but if quotation gets confirm then it will so in the orders menu too.

and for default value you can use `default_get` method to pass default values in fields.
but put their some condition if you need to separate quotation and sale order,
For ex:-
if `self.state in ['draft', 'sent']:` then put your default value in field for quotation.

Comment: I don't think you can inspect record fields while computing defaults, because the record doesn't exist yet.